# Aligning image list items to center horizontal

Tags: css

[image]

**I want my facebook icon to aligned in center(horizontally not vertically, so that it comes between my collapse button and twitter icon).** I tried text-align but it isn't working..! Any other way I can do it ?

My relevant HTML code

```
<button type="button" style="float:left;" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
<ul>
  <li class="horiz1">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="blank"><img src="img/facebook.png" style="width:28px;" ></a>
  </li>
  <li class="horiz">
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" style="width:35px;" ></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My relevant CSS code

```
.horiz { display: inline; float: right;}
.horiz1 { display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I tried text-align but it isn't working..*

Where did you tried?
Apply that property to `ul` tag, like...

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/ovwnw90u/

Comment: Ohh.you are right, I tried it with my horiz1 class..!

Answer (score 1):

use margin-top to make it come down a little.
Edited: Try using this :

```
.horiz
{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be centered..!

Answer (score 0):

Set the Heights of the images equal to get them centered.